# make a transformation of dataframe

Tags: pandas

I need advice to transform a DataFrame `df` from

```
               timestamp   group        v1    v2    
0    11/14/2019 00:00:00      g1      0.00    1      
1    11/14/2019 00:00:00      g2      0.00    2
```

to

```
          timestamp   new_group         v 
11/14/2019 00:00:00       g1_v1      0.00    
11/14/2019 00:00:00       g1_v2         1
11/14/2019 00:00:00       g2_v1      0.00    
11/14/2019 00:00:00       g2_v2         2
```

The logic is to combine `v1` with `v2` then make it as a new column as `v`, meanwhile, create a new column `new_group` which join the original `group` value and original column name(`v1` or `v2`) as its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)** the dataframe, combine the new columns created into one using **[str cat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html)** and **[filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)** for required columns

```
res = (df
       .melt(['timestamp','group'])
       .assign(new_group = lambda x: x.group.str.cat(x.variable,sep="_"))
       .filter(['timestamp','new_group','value'])
      )

res


       timestamp    new_group   value
0   11/14/2019 00:00:00 g1_v1   0.0
1   11/14/2019 00:00:00 g2_v1   0.0
2   11/14/2019 00:00:00 g1_v2   1.0
3   11/14/2019 00:00:00 g2_v2   2.0
```